# socket recv Python, как сделать признак окончания блока данных если они меньше буфера приема recv

Tags: python, сокет

у меня клиент отправляет данные из списка в цикле
 for i in spisok : socket.sendall(i)
элементы списка имеют разную длину от 20 до 500 байт. на сервере мне нужно получить каждый элемент как как он есть и в неизменном виде отправить на обработку
while True: data=socket.recv(1024), data.foo
но почему то на приемной стороне функция recv на сервере иногда склеивает отправленные из клиента блоки, и отдает в переменную уже склеенный блок вместо того чтоб каждый раз возвращать отдельно отправленный блок. Как дать recv(1024) что блок получен и надо вернуть его? Можно ли как то указывать длину блока при передаче sendall(i)?

Answer (score 1):

Все получилось с разделением блоков признаком разделения b'\n'

Отправляю так
`socket.sendall(data+b'\n')`

получаю так

`struct=[]
struct = socket.recv(1024).split(b'\n')
for i in struct:
    foo(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Сделай протокол  по типу tlv. Отправляешь сначала длинну, потом тело. На приемнике читай 2байта на длинну, потом читай сколько там указанно.

Или используй стандарт вроде mqtt.